# NSFetchedResultsController initial fetch slow

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsoperation

I am working on my first core data app and am working with `NSFetchedResultsController`. My issue is that the initial fetch is slow, so when my tableview slides into view there is a pause as the initial fetch is called and blocks the UI. In all the examples I have seen the initial fetch is done in `viewDidLoad`. I was wondering if this can be done in an `NSOperation` to avoid blocking the main thread?

What I'm not sure about is how to pass the `NSFetchedResultsController` to to `NSOperation` in a thread safe way. Is this possible? if not how does one go about ensure that the UI is not blocked when doing the initial fetch on the FRC.

Comment: Does your model contain an NSData attribute which holds an image or a large object? If yes, this could be the root problem. In your fetchRequest object set the "setPropertiesToFetch" and see if it makes any difference. Only get the properties that the table view displays.

Comment: Also make sure that your batch size is set to a reasonable amount.  25-100.  You also may want check out the latest Core Data Recipes code, there is an optimization using GCD that Apple is using with respect to setting up the Persistent Store Coordinator that helps with application launching armies nd blocking the UI.

Comment: @iKJ - it holds approx 10 strings and 10 ints. The strings will not be longer than about 50 chars. I just tried "setPropertiesToFetch". From looking at the docs you also need to setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType but I don't think that works with NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: @timthetoolman - I have batch set to 20. If you are referring to TopSongs example code that performs the fetching in viewDidLoad too

Comment: no am referring to the new "Recipes" sample code.

Comment: @timthetoolman - The Recipies example performs the fetch in ViewDidLoad too. If I find a way of performing the fetch in a separate thread I will post the answer here but for now it looks like when using a NSFetchedResultsController you have to perform the fetch on the main thread which can impact on the smoothness of the UI if your dataset is large or the predicate has several terms

Comment: Look at the Recipes code that has been modified to support iCloud.